# How to prove there always exists a two variables or one variable equation corresponding to a curve drawn on a 2D plane?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to prove there always exists a two variables or one variable equation corresponding to a curve drawn on a 2D plane?

For example, a circle 's equation is $x^2+y^2=r^2$.

Comment: This is the content of the Implicit Function Theorem. It is one of the most important theorems in all of analysis.

Comment: What is your definition of "curve drawn on a 2D plane"?

Comment: The Implicit Function Theorem goes the wrong way I think: it says (under certain conditions) a level curve $F(x,y)=c$ is locally the graph of a function.  But it looks to me like Victor wants to start with a parametric curve and write that as a level curve.

Answer (score 0):

Since Victor didn't specify what he means by "a curve drawn ...", I'll assume that
this is a parametric curve $p = \gamma(t)$, $0 \le t \le 1$, with $\gamma: [0,1] \to \mathbb R^2$ continuous.  The image $C = \gamma([0,1])$ is then a compact set in the plane, and $F(p) = \text{dist}(p, C)$ (i.e. the distance from $p$ to $C$) is a continuous function on $\mathbb R^2$ such that $C = \{p: F(p) = 0\}$, i.e. 
$F(p)= 0$ can be taken to be the "equation" of the curve.